# Access DataStore for grid from within scope of GridFilter

Tags: extjs

In this example:http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?14503-Grid-Filter-(Plugin), at the bottom of the page, the 'buildQuery' method of the gridfilter is overridden to provide custom logic. the scope of the methos is GridFilter. If in this scope, I want to access the datastore of the grid, can I do it?

The objective is to add the filter parameters to the 'baseParams' of the datastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The store is a property of the Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters object. As such, you should be able to access it normally using `this.store`

From the example at the bottom of the page you've linked to it should be as easy as the following:

```
plugins: new Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters({
    buildQuery: function(filters){
        this.store.
        var p = {};
        for(var i=0, len=filters.length; i<len; i++){
            // Custom filter serialization

            //not sure what format filters comes in
            this.store.setBaseParam('your_param', filters[i])
        }

        return p;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. Out of curiosity, if 'your_param' was an array, and we wish to add filters[i](i=1,2...n) to the existing 'your_param' without overwriting it completely, does the syntax allow for that? SOmething like: this.store.getBaseParams().get('your_param').append(filters[i]))

Comment: Not quite. The store allows access to BaseParams through a public property **baseParams** which is an object. AFAIK, if **your_param** is an array, you would need to do something like the following:
var myParam = this.baseParams.your_param;
myParam.push(filters[i]);
this.store.setBaseParam('your_param', myParam);